# Is it possible to change data source dynamically in WSO2DSS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Currently we are using WSO2DSS for exchanging data between PHP and Database. Now we just faced multiple data source some reason. Means, We will select data source from PHP side and our DSS should be connect to database based on that given data source.

How it be done?

BR,
Eba

Answer (score 0):

You can define two Data Services and call the right data service from the PHP itself based on your logic rather than defining things dynamically in the DSS.

Comment: so you are suggesting to basically duplicate the Data Service with just their own Data Source each, right? Don't you think this could result in a expensive process if we are talking about a considerably big Data Services stack deployed on the DSS? is there any other way to solve this problem?